# Get fully qualified template template argument name using libtooling

Tags: c++, clang, template-templates, libtooling

I am trying to use `libtooling` to print a `CXXRecordDecl` of the substantiation of a template class with a template template parameter. Unfortunately, the string representation of the template template parameter is not fully qualified (e.g. it's missing namespaces).

I am printing the `CXXRecordDecl` with this code:

```
clang::PrintingPolicy policy = compiler_instance->getLangOpts();
std::string name = decl->getTypeForDecl()->getCanonicalTypeInternal().getAsString(policy);
```

Here is an example where I would expect the output to be `ns::A<ns::B>`, but I get `ns::A<B>`:

```cpp
namespace ns {

template <template <class> class T>
class A {
  T<int> x;
};

template <class T>
class B {
  T y;
};

} // namespace ns

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  using namespace ns;
  A<B> z;
}
```

**How do I print the fully-qualified name of a class with a template template parameter?**

On a related note, is there a way to do this without calling `getCanonicalTypeInternal`, which sounds like an internal function?

**[Edit #1]** I've also tried `decl->getQualifiedNameAsString()`, which completely omits the template arguments and outputs `ns::A`.

**[Edit #2]** Cling trades one set of problems for another. It does correctly produce fully-qualified types for template template parameters. However, it produces unqualified names for the argument and return types of functions (and function pointers). For example, the below code produces the output `ns::A<void (B)>` instead of `ns::A<void (ns::B)>`:

```cpp
namespace ns {

class B { };

template <class T>
class A { };

} // namespace

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  using namespace ns;

  A<void (B)> x;
}
```

**[Edit #3]** I posted [an issue on the Cling issue tracker](https://sft.its.cern.ch/jira/browse/ROOT-7806) for the above issue. Note that viewing the page requires that you sign in with a CERN lightweight account. See [this page](https://account.cern.ch/account/Externals/) for instructions to create an account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Try this: `decl->getQualifiedNameAsString();`

Looks like at current moment `clang/libclang` has suitable
parts, but no the suitable and simple solution that just print full name,

see this http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-dev/2015-October/045473.html

but there is `cling` project based on `clang` that implement such functionality,
see look here:

https://root.cern.ch/gitweb?p=root.git;a=blob;f=interpreter/cling/include/cling/Utils/AST.h;h=91cea2ef82f6a6b2ed4671d43253b1c0ebd86fd4;hb=HEAD

```
std::string GetFullyQualifiedName(clang::QualType QT,
                                        const clang::ASTContext &Ctx);
```

is exactly what you looking for, after applying for your example it return `ns::A<ns::B>`

looks like they integrate this functionality into next or after next `clang/libclang` release, so hope the best.

Comment: `decl->getQualifiedNameAsString()` outputs `ns::A`. This is actually worse - it completely omits the template arguments.

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I am looking for. Much like the poster on the LLVM mailing list, I'm quite surprised that this is not available in libtooling.

Comment: Cling *does* correctly handle template template arguments. However, it produces unqualified type names for function argument and return values. Any ideas?